# Referencing the TreeView from other TreeViews

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a window form that has a control treeViewMain and in the code I have a list of treeViews that has variable number of treeViews. I want the treeViewMain to show anyone of the treeView from the list.

```
treeViewMain=treeViews[0];
```

but the form is not showing the tree. Also I have thoroughly checked the treeViews in the list, they are populating correctly.

Comment: were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: yeah I solved the problem by clearing all the childs of treeViewMain and then adding childs of treeViews[0] to treeViewMain @MongZhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently simple assigning does not work. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41845646/5174469) it seems that the parent of a `TreeViewNode` has to be unique and there by the "fruit" can only sit at one tree.

One workaround could be to set the parent property of the `TreeView` in your list to the `treeViewMain`:

```
treeViews[0].Parent = treeViewMain;
```

this will put the treeview from the list as a child inside `treeViewMain`. If you want to change that and load the next item from your list you need to make sure that the previously loaded item's parent property is set to null before assigning a new parent like in this example:

```
private int count = 0;

private void button_ChooseTreeView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (count > 0)
    {
        treeViews[count -1].Parent = null;
    }
    treeViews[count].Parent = treeViewMain;
    count++;
}
```

The other possibility would be to clone each node and populate the `treeViewMain` each time you want to update the list items to the display